# Mimic Firebase client library's structure and patterns

Tags: javascript, firebase, static-libraries, javascript-objects

I'm thinking about making my own JavaScript client library, and I like the way Firebase formats requests. I'm trying to understand whats going on. From looking at the web guide [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html) I found the below code:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/saving-data/fireblog");

var usersRef = ref.child("users");

usersRef.set({

    alanisawesome: {
      date_of_birth: "June 23, 1912",
      full_name: "Alan Turing"
    },

    gracehop: {
      date_of_birth: "December 9, 1906",
      full_name: "Grace Hopper"
    }

});
```

I can see that `ref` is equal to a function called `Firebase`, and `usersRef` is equal to `ref.child`.

I'm imagining something like this:

```
 Firebase = function(url) {
    this.child = function(path) {

  console.log(url);
  console.log(path);

};
};
```

Here I can see that `usersRef.set` is being called but I can't figure out how or where this would go? Is `set` a function or an object? I notice firebase has `set()`, `update()`, `push()` and `transaction()`, making me think these are functions.

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
```

Maybe I'm on the wrong path totally, I'm just not familiar with this pattern.

Comment: @Drenmi thank you for that edit, it looks and reads much better.

Comment: `child()` just needs to return an object with `set`/`update`/… method, just like `new Firebase` returns an object with a `child` method.

Comment: @Bergi thank you for your reply, i just cant get my head around your suggestion, could you help further by expanding my best guess so far.

Comment: I made a JSbin here https://jsbin.com/leqosuxavo/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the Firebase API, you will see that `child()` returns a new Firebase reference to the child location. So something like this:

```
var Firebase = function(url) {

   console.log(url);

   this.child = function(path) {
      return new Firebase(url+'/'+path);
   };

   this.set = function(object) {
      console.log(object);
   };

};
```

I've updated you jsbin: https://jsbin.com/nucume/2/edit?js,console